# With MVVMLight on android, how do I send a parameter to a Command on the ViewModel?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm-light

I want to execute a Command on a ViewModel when a button is clicked, but the Command should receive a parameter when called.

I got this working:

```
button.SetCommand<object>("Click", vm.MenuItemCommand)
```

where the Command looks like this:

```
public RelayCommand<object> MenuItemCommand { get; private set; }
```

When I click the button, the Command does get executed, however, the parameter is null.

So, my question is, how do I set up the binding between my button and the command, so that a parameter DOES get sent to the Command on the ViewModel?

Thank you.

Comment: I have not used Xamarin as of now but by any chance button has button.SetCommandParamenter() method??? If so try using it.

Comment: @Tabrej, There is no SetCommandParameter() extension method for the Button.

Comment: Check [this link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3684/mvvmcross-passing-parameter) hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to send data to another Activity, I want to send a parameter into a Command on a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel

```
private ClassA _classA;
public ClassA ClassA
{
    get
    {
        return this._classA;
    }
    set
    {
        this._classA = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ClassA));
    }
}

public ICommand ImplementingCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<ClassA>(OnImplementing); } }

private void OnEdit(ClassA param){
    ... do something here...
}
```

View

```
<Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ClassA}" >
```

You can base of something like this. Ofc there are more than one way of passing param for the command, but this is one of the easy example that you can follow! For the relaycommand, make sure that you have mvvmlightlibs installed, that way you won't have to implement relaycommand yourself.. all you have to do is in your class that belong to viewmodel, do something like

```
public ClassA ClassA:ViewModelBase
```

this way, you won't need to implement relaycommand and raisepropertychange, you can use the one from mvvmlight